# Powershell Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using PowerShell for the first time. I am trying to use a script that lets me get some attributes from Active Directory of all the people in a group. Below is a script that I found and tried using but it gave me an error. \

**my OU.csv has content:**

Dn
"OU=something,OU=something1,DC=something2,DC=com"

**UserInfo.txt is empty**

**SearchAD_UserInfo:**

```
# Search Active Directory and Get User Information 
# 
# www.sivarajan.com 
# 

clear 
 $UserInfoFile = New-Item -type file -force "C:\Scripts\UserInfo.txt"  
"samaccountname`tgivenname`tSN" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII 
 Import-CSV "C:\Scripts\OU.csv" | ForEach-Object { 
  $dn = $_.dn 
  $ObjFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectCategory=Person))" 
  $objSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
  $objSearch.PageSize = 15000 
  $objSearch.Filter = $ObjFilter 
  $objSearch.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$dn" 
  $AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll() 
  foreach ($Obj in $AllObj) 
      { $objItemS = $Obj.Properties 
             $Ssamaccountname = $objItemS.samaccountname 
             $SsamaccountnameGN = $objItemS.givenname 
             $SsamaccountnameSN = $objItemS.sn 
             "$Ssamaccountname`t$SsamaccountnameGN`t$SsamaccountnameSN" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII -append 
   }
```

**Error:**

```
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At C:\Path\SearchAD_UserInfo
+    }  <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseBra
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the `ForEach-Object` is not terminated.  Change:

```
foreach ($Obj in $AllObj) 
      { $objItemS = $Obj.Properties 
             $Ssamaccountname = $objItemS.samaccountname 
             $SsamaccountnameGN = $objItemS.givenname 
             $SsamaccountnameSN = $objItemS.sn 
             "$Ssamaccountname`t$SsamaccountnameGN`t$SsamaccountnameSN" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII -append 
   }
```

To:

```
foreach ($Obj in $AllObj) 
      { $objItemS = $Obj.Properties 
             $Ssamaccountname = $objItemS.samaccountname 
             $SsamaccountnameGN = $objItemS.givenname 
             $SsamaccountnameSN = $objItemS.sn 
             "$Ssamaccountname`t$SsamaccountnameGN`t$SsamaccountnameSN" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII -append 
      } # End of foreach
   } # End of ForEach-Object
```